# Reading property from JSON object in Javascript with colons

Tags: json, object, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a JSON object **[image: queue.CountDetails]** which I can console log out fine. However whenever I try to read the properties of this object I am getting "Unexpected token :" error. The json object does have a colon in it. How do i escape that colon and console.log the individual properties of the object. See that attached image for info

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out JSON serializer to get the JSON value. You can't get the JSON value without serializing it. So To serialize, you can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Json")`. Check it out this link below for JSON serialization.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

For serializing the JSON you should install Newtonsoft JSON package in your visual studio.